# Performance of cassandra on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I am looking to deploy a single node cassandra on aws m4.large instance. Our use case is more read oriented i.e there will be much more reads than writes. We have around 1 gb data now. Now i am wondering about latency of each read and write? Also how many concurrent read a single node can handle? And i am very confused about when to scale i.e have another node deployed. Does this depend solely on data size or we have to scale if read write request reaches a certain limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casssandra can handle quite an amount of requests per node. You will want to look at `cassandra-stress` (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress_t.html) and `YCSB` (https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki) for some testing.

Cassandra can be scaled out to hande more data (more disk space, same replication factor), or to handle more requests (more replicas) or even both.

1GB of data is such a small value you an m4.large value can keep all your data in memory - if you need really low latency you can enable the row cache with a proper value of `row_cache_size_in_mb` and maybe `row_cache_save_period` (see https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSetCaching.html for caching details). Then all your data will be cached in memory all the time and you can get really low latencies. Fast disks (`io1`) will also give you lower latency.

But try for yourself with some testing.